# Extending partial file-local type with source generatrors

Tags: c#, partial-classes, sourcegenerators

I was curious if it would be possible for a Source Generator to extend a partial file-local type such as:

```cs
namespace Bar;

file partial class Foo
{
    // Omitted for brevity...
}
```

I tried to output the following code snippet in the `RegisterSourceOutput` method:

```cs
ctx.AddSource("Foo.cs", 
"""
namespace Bar;
    
file partial class Foo
{
    public int FooBar { get; set; }
}
""");
```

Note that the generated hint name is the same as the "target" file name.
Anyhow, with IL Spy I can see that it generates two types which look something like this:

```
internal class <Foo>FFC769A3FDE8D9AC06720D6E176DDEAEFDBCA21D74E682A2556B5EC23F5D641E3__Foo
```

Instead of a single one, which Is what I am trying to achieve.